# How to make multiple api calls with python requests

Tags: python, django, api, python-requests, sendasynchronousrequest

I am trying to make parallel calls to external apis from django using requests or any other library that allows me to do this.

I have already tried using grequests to make this calls, sometimes it works but most times I get 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'json' error on the client side. 
Here are my codes

views.py

```
def get_fixtures(request, league_id):
league_id = league_id

urls = [
    "https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/fixtures/league/%d" % league_id,
    "https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/leagues/league/%d" % league_id
]
headers = {'X-RapidAPI-Host': "api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com", 'X-RapidAPI-Key': X_RapidAPI_Key}
resp = (grequests.get(u, headers=headers) for u in urls)
responses = grequests.map(resp)
a = responses[0].json()
b = responses[1].json()
fix_1 = a['api']['fixtures']
api_2 = b['api']['leagues']

context = {

    'fix_1': fix_1,
    'api_2': api_2,
}

return render(request, "pages/fixtures.html", context)
```

On the server side i get this error:

```
File "src\gevent\_greenlet_primitives.py", line 60, in 
gevent.__greenlet_primitives.SwitchOutGreenletWithLoop.switch
File "src\gevent\_greenlet_primitives.py", line 64, in 
gevent.__greenlet_primitives.SwitchOutGreenletWithLoop.switch
File "src\gevent\__greenlet_primitives.pxd", line 35, in 
gevent.__greenlet_primitives._greenlet_switch
greenlet.error: cannot switch to a different thread.
```

Can I use requests or any other library to perform the calls without getting these errors? if yes how do i implement it in my work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try placing this:

```
resp = list(grequests.get(u, headers=headers) for u in urls)
```

Comment: This was helpful. It seems to work better. But I still get:  File 
     "src\gevent\__greenlet_primitives.pxd", line 35, in 
     gevent.__greenlet_primitives._greenlet_switch
     greenlet.error: cannot switch to a different thread. on my local server

Comment: @Bruce Did you ever solve this? I am having the same issue